# dataframe failing to be converted to parquet

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for two days and haven't been successful so reaching out to the community.

I have a dataframe which has almost a million rows, and when I am trying to convert the dataframe to a parquet, I am getting the following error.

```
 Check failed: (item_builder_->length()) == (key_builder_->length()) keys and items builders don't have the same size in MapBuilder
```

Looking at the error I thought that some keys who have maps as value is causing this error.
So, I looked at the possible culprit columns in our case lets call the column `geos`.
In the schema,

```
geos: map<string, string>
```

So, I am getting the error

```
 Check failed: (item_builder_->length()) == (key_builder_->length()) keys and items builders don't have the same size in MapBuilder
```

when I am converting the whole df.

1. I thought that maybe one of the values of `geos` is not valid. So to find that row, I tried to individually convert each row to parquet. Surprisingly, all rows managed to convert to parquet.

Now, I think that this error is because of some column size limit that fast-parquet/pyarrow has.
I am using the versions

```
pyarrow==9.0.0
pandas==1.2.5
```

Anyone has experienced this before and can validate my reasoning?

Help with reasoning about the error

Comment: `I tried to individually convert each row to parquet.` how did you do that?

Comment: for i in range(len(df)):
     df_temp = df[i]
     df_temp.to_parquet("temp.parquet")